# SQL: Rank by/Filter by total rank

Tags: time-series, amazon-redshift

I have a pretty standard "append only" table with `created_at` and `group_name` as columns using Amazon Redshift.

I want to produce a time series of the top N rows by group for the past [time range].

Currently I use this:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', created_at) AS timeseries,
    my_table.group_name,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    my_table
JOIN (
    SELECT
        group_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rank
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
    GROUP BY
        group_name
    ) ranking ON (ranking.group_name = my_table.group_name)
WHERE
    created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
GROUP BY
    timeseries,
    my_table.group_name,
    ranking.rank
HAVING 
    ranking.rank <= 5
ORDER BY
    timeseries DESC
```

This is pretty error prone to change because the filtering of `created_at` range is present twice, causing issues if it needs to change.

Is there a way to make this query more elegant (ideally using the time filter only once)?

Comment: Do you want the top 5 rows per group? This appears to select the top 5 groups with the most rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can add join condition for the created_at,

for example calculate max and min for the created_at and bring all the data between

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', created_at) AS timeseries,
    my_table.group_name,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    my_table
JOIN (
    SELECT
        group_name,
        max(created_at) as max_createed,
        min(created_at) as min_createed,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rank
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
    GROUP BY
        group_name
    ) ranking ON (ranking.group_name = my_table.group_name)
AND created_ad between min_created and max_created
GROUP BY
    timeseries,
    my_table.group_name,
    ranking.rank
HAVING 
    ranking.rank <= 5
ORDER BY
    timeseries DESC
```

also, i believed there are more elegant ways to calculate that without bring the same table twice

Comment: Care to share more about the more elegant way?

Comment: for that i need more data , for example if the group_name is a unique value on daily bases ?

Comment: No, it's a `BYTEDICT` that holds less than ~40 values in total

Answer (score 0):

try this one, also the ruining should be  faster

```
    SELECT
        ranking.date AS timeseries,
        ranking.group_name,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM
        my_table
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            group_name,
            date(created_at) as date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date(created_at) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rank
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
        GROUP BY
            group_name,
            date(created_at) as date
        ) ranking 
 WHERE rank <=5
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is not very accurate - if there are dips in the time series, the top N will now show correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your requirements completely but this query should give the top 5 groups per day.

```
select timeseries, group_name, count from (
    select timeseries, group_name, count,
        row_number() over (partition by timeseries order by count desc) as rank
    from (
        select date_trunc('day', created_at) AS timeseries,
            group_name,
            count(*) AS count
        from my_table
        where created_at > sysdate - '1 day'::interval
        group by 1,2
    )
) where rank <= 5
order by 1 desc
```

This query should give the counts per day for the overall top 5 groups:

```
with daily_counts as (
    select date_trunc('day', created_at) AS timeseries,
        group_name,
        count(*) AS count
    from my_table
    where created_at > sysdate - '1 day'::interval
    group by 1,2
)
select d.timeseries, d.group_name, d.count
from daily_counts d
join (
    select group_name, sum(count) as total
    from daily_counts
    group by group_name order by total desc
    limit 5
) r on d.group_name=r.group_name
order by 1,3 desc
```